# Uploading file with nginx results in 408 / EAGAIN

Tags: linux, laravel, nginx

I have a php application running on Ubuntu server 18.04, provisioned with laravel forge. Everything works fine except for uploading images with a multipart/form-data html form. This results in an error connection timeout.

Looking into nginx i found these messages when trying to upload a file:

```
[pid 12937] setsockopt(16, SOL_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, [1], 4) = 0
[pid 12937] accept4(11, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(58384), sin_addr=inet_addr("MY_IP")}, [112->16], SOCK_NONBLOCK) = 16
[pid 12937] accept4(11, 0x7ffc48f7dd00, [112], SOCK_NONBLOCK) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
[pid 12937] recvfrom(16, "\26", 1, MSG_PEEK, NULL, NULL) = 1
```

The 'EAGAIN' message means that there are no connections available for the socket to use. However, I find this strange because i'm the only one sending requests to this server and the nginx 'worker_connections' is set to 768.

**Update:** I found out this problem only exists when i'm using my work laptop with ethernet plugged in. Any other machine in the office works fine, also my work laptop works fine over WiFi. So it is not a server side issue but has to do something with my ethernet connection. I've swapped around ethernet cables with colleagues that don't have this problem on their laptop, that doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Do you use `php-fpm`? Can you send your configure?

Answer (score 2):

As you know, A 408 Request Timeout message is an HTTP status code that is returned to the client when a request to the server takes longer than the server’s allocated timeout window.

If you have this error (408), You can check these items on your server:

- `php-fpm` configure (Do not limit requests)
- check below items in `nginx.conf`:

  - `client_body_timeout`
  - `client_header_timeout`
  - `keepalive_timeout`

If you still have a problem, You can read this post: [408 Request Timeout: What It Is and How to Fix It](https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/408-request-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

You may ensure there is no limit on server-side, what is the output of?

```
ulimit -a
```

Answer (score -1):

408 is a client side timeout which means your browser or client is closing out the connection. It’s not the server, rather you need to tune your client if you are using a custom client.

If you are using a standard browser, then the best way to handle this situation is to throw a client side JS which keeps sending a keep alive request ensuring that the browser does not timeout the connection.

In order to debug, try fiddling around the timeouts in firefox browser by going to `network.http.connection-timeout` in `about:config`

If that solves, then implement a keepalive